# Load multidimensional VBA Array from disk

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to save and then load a multi-dimensional VBA array to/from disk. According to the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278468%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the number of dimensions are saved as a descriptor in the file, but I can't figure out how to access/load them.  The example below works, but only because I have hard coded the array dimensions.  The commented out line works in a dynamic sense, but the array's dimensions are lost in the process.

Here's some sample code:

```
Sub WriteArray()
Dim file_name As String
Dim file_length As Long
Dim fnum As Integer

Dim values() As Boolean
ReDim values(1 To 5, 1 To 10, 1 To 20)

Dim i As Integer 'Populate the simple array
    For i = 1 To 20
    values(1, 1, i) = True
Next

' Delete existing file (if any).
file_name = "array.to.file.vba.bin"
On Error Resume Next
Kill file_name
On Error GoTo 0

' Save the file.
fnum = FreeFile
Open file_name For Binary As #fnum
Put #fnum, 1, values
Close fnum

End Sub

Sub ReadArray()
Dim file_name As String
Dim file_length As Long
Dim fnum As Integer
Dim newArray() As Boolean

file_name = "array.to.file.vba.bin" 'txtFile.Text"
fnum = FreeFile

file_length = FileLen(file_name)
'ReDim newArray(1 To file_length) 'This loads the data, but not with the right dimensions.

ReDim newArray(1 To 5, 1 To 10, 1 To 20) 'This works but with dimensions hard coded.

'How to re-dim here using the dimensions saved in the file?

Open file_name For Binary As #fnum
Get #fnum, 1, newArray
Close fnum

End Sub
```

I need to give credit to the VB Helper website because the example above is based on one they posted [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_read_write_binary_file.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I didn't know this VBA technique which allows to write array into text file. Or maybe I forgot it. :) Therefore I dived into it.

**1st. Writing to the file.**

I have some problems with `Boolean` type of your array. It's not working but it's working with `Variant type`. And I changed open mode from `Binary` to `Random`. Moreover, I used `Len parameter` for `Open Statement` with value according to [this MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251802%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

This is the first sub improved:

```
Sub WriteArray()

    Dim file_name As String
    Dim file_length As Long
    Dim fnum As Integer

    Dim values() As Variant
    ReDim values(1 To 5, 1 To 10, 1 To 20)

    Dim i As Integer 'Populate the simple array
        For i = 1 To 20
            values(1, 1, i) = True
        Next

    ' Delete existing file (if any).
    file_name = "array.to.file.vba.bin"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill file_name
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Save the file.
    fnum = FreeFile

    '<<<<<<< this is new >>>>>>>
    Dim arrLen As Long
        arrLen = (2 + 3 * 8) + (5 * 10 * 20 * 3)

    '<<<<<<< this is changed >>>>>>>
    Open file_name For Random As #fnum Len = arrLen
    Put #fnum, 1, values
    Close fnum

End Sub
```

**2nd. Reading from file**

Our array will be `Variant type dynamic`. I changed file open type to `Random` from `Binary` and used `Len parameter` with the max possible value according to [this MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

This is the second sub improved:

```
Sub ReadArray()
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim newArray() As Variant

    file_name = "array.to.file.vba.bin" 'txtFile.Text"
    fnum = FreeFile

    '<<<<<<< this is new >>>>>>>
    Dim lenAAA
        lenAAA = 32767  '>>> MAX possible value

    '<<<<<<< this is changed >>>>>>>
    Open file_name For Random As #fnum Len = lenAAA
    Get #fnum, 1, newArray
    Close fnum

End Sub
```

**Screen shot of variables value.**

[image]

Comment: This is helpful.  At least I can get it running now.  I had noticed that the maximum file length was 32,767, but I thought it applied to a "different" type of file.  Now that I realize that it will affect me, I may have to save my arrays in pieces (Re-loading and assembling them will still be faster than re-running them). I was hoping to find a solution where I could use the array descriptor that is "automatically" written to disk by VBA.  But, it doesn't seem that anyone really uses it that feature much for multi-dimensional arrays (or, at least I couldn't find any examples online).

Comment: @D.Woods, depending of your goal, you could explore `ADODB` feature of writing data to file or `FileSystemObject` as an alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the additional advice.  I wasn't familiar with ADODB so I took a look.  Unfortunately, I don't think it will work in my case because it requires a Windows version of Excel.  I am developing for a multi-user environment where the product needs to be usable on both OS X, and Windows versions of Excel.